# How to add a Timer

Tags: android

I am doing such thing

```
Add a timer to the autocompletes for .5 seconds before 
sending a request to the server. If the user types before the 
.5 timer, reset the timer.
```

i am trying inside of onTextChanged()

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          /*  String newText = s.toString();
            if(!newText.trim().equals(""))
                Autocompletes_Timer(newText);*/
        }

private Handler handler;
private void Autocompletes_Timer(final String newText) {

    if(handler!= null)
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable(newText), 500);

}
```

please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class SomeClass extends Activity implements TextWatcher {

    private Handler serverHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
       serverHandler = new Handler();
       ...

    }

    ...

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       if(!newText.trim().equals(""))
          serverHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
          serverHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                   @Override
                   public void run() {

                   //Do somthing there 

                   }
               }, 500);
          }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                //Do somthing there 

                }
            }, 5000);
```

Comment: This, and also cancel all pending runnables on the handler with handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) if the text changes before 0.5 seconds. Otherwise all requests will be send anyway.

Comment: If I get the question right it says DOT 5, which means 500 ms. Not sure if typo

Comment: thx joris. may u please make a code for "This, and also cancel all pending runnables on the handler with handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) if the text changes before 0.5 seconds. Otherwise all requests will be send anyway
'

Comment: What I do is make a the Handler a class variable and before the postDelayed I cancel all messages with handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null). Also, cancel all messages in  the onDestroy callback

Comment: ok, but how may i know that user is typing fast so that i will not wait for .5 second and will send request to server